# How do you remove the bindings from a VS Team project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

How do you remove the bindings from a VS Team project, is it just a matter of deleting ".vspscc" files?

What is the best way to do this, say I have a project on CodePlex and it is time to package it up for release, but by default the bindings come with the source so when others open the solution it interferes with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to unbind from source control:

1. Open your project
2. File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control
3. Select your project(s)
4. Click "Unbind"

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (under TFS, not codeplex)

Copy or move the project folder out of your workspace (I put it in `c:\temp`), and then open it in VS2008.

Visual studio then shows the following prompt:

> The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding information cannot be found. Because it is not possible to recover this missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings are missing will be treated as not under source control.

After this, another dialog appears, as follows:

> The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding information cannot be found. Because it is not possible to recover this missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings are missing will be treated as not under source control.

And you can chose *Temporarily work uncontrolled*, or *Permanently remove source control association bindings*.

Select the latter, do a *Save All*, and reload the solution. Profit!

Comment: This sounds more like a hack... There's a UI item to do this, see below.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still learning my way around TFS. It seems entirely too complicated for it's own good (coming from SVN)